# Why does background-color:attribute break when previous line contains comments?

Tags: html, css, styles, comments

So I was experimenting with internal stylesheets on the latest version of chrome and it seems that there is a bug that breaks the code.

For some reason, I can not add any comments before background-color:rgb(51,51,51) without causing the code to fail.

Here is my code (background color doesn't change):

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style> 
        body {
            width:100%; <!--browser screen must be fixed width-->
            height:100%; <!--and height-->
            margin:0px; <!--removes uneven margin added to row's margins-->
            background-color:rgb(51,51,51); <!--note that height and width must be specified to work-->
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>
        Headline
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my other code (this time background works):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style> 
        body {
            background-color:rgb(51,51,51); <!--note that height and width must be specified to work-->
            width:100%; <!--browser screen must be fixed width-->
            height:100%; <!--and height-->
            margin:0px; <!--removes uneven margin added to row's margins-->
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>
        Headline
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that the comments might not make sense (I removed extra code but kept the comments). So what exactly is going on? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong comment syntax , use block comment

```
/* my comment */
```

Comment: I'm going to mark you as the correct answer since you answered sooner. I knew /* \*/ was the comment syntax for css, but I thought since the code was in an html file, I would have to use the html syntax. Changing it to /* \*/ did indeed work. Edit: it takes 5 minutes for me to be allowed to mark the answer, I'll do it later.

Answer (score 3):

As defined in [CSS2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#comments):

> > Comments begin with the characters "/*" and end with the characters "*/"

So you should use `/*  */` comments in CSS.

However HTML style comments `<!-- -->` are also possible, but *the only valid position* for them is wrapping entire CSS rules block:

```
<style>
    <!--
    body {
        background-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin:0px;
        color: red;
    }
    -->
</style>
```

`<!-- -->` delimiters are used to to prevent CSS blocks from being displayed by browsers that don't support HTML 3.2. (this is the same as wrapping Javascript code with `<!-- -->`). These are very ancient user-agents though.

Answer (score 1):

in css you dont comment this way like html, use comment this way instead

```
 /* background: grey ;  */
```